# Add the attribute in existing elements in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to create the scrollbar in the Text widget. I search on google and have seen the existing SO questions but I'm not get the proper example.

```
mycontainer = Text(root)
scrollbar = Scrollbar(mycontainer)
scrollbar.pack( side = RIGHT, fill=Y )

#here I want to add the attribute of yscrollcommand into the mycontainer

mycontainer = Text(yscrollcommand = scrollbar.set) #Not working 

for line in range(100):
   mycontainer.insert(END, "This is line number " + str(line))


mycontainer.place(x=5, y=40, width=500, height=500)
scrollbar.config( command = mycontainer.yview )
```

How can I do it properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem is that you recreate `mycontainer` after you create the `Scrollbar` instance. That means that the scrollbar disappears. Try

```
mycontainer.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
```

instead. Another (small) problem is that you need to finish your inserts with a linebreak like this:

```
for line in range(100):
    mycontainer.insert(END, "This is line number " + str(line) + "\n")
```

The third problem is that the scrollbarslider isn't shown correctly (even not with `scrollbar.activate('slider')`). I have to say that I couldn't solve the last problem. To see all options for the `.config()` command, type `mycontainer.keys()` and `scrollbar.keys()`.

Comment: Ok, I didn't get the third problem anymore when I used exactly the order of statements like the question shows :) and I didn't need `scrollbar.activate('slider')`