# Mac OS: Tkinter Scrollbar widget has no keys

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, tkinter, scrollbar

When I type following code lines in the python console, I get an unexpected output:

```
>>> from Tkinter import *
>>> root = Tk()
>>> frame = Frame(root)
>>> sb = Scrollbar(frame)
>>> sb.keys()
['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
>>>
```

I actually expected some `.config()` arguments like `'command'` or `'fill'`. I can't remember such weird behavior on windows though.

Comment: This is a bug in tkinter. Why do you need a list of keys? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: well, I'm not able to use the scrollbar. I actually want to show some text in a label. the label is in a frame which is in a canvas. the scrollbar is actually part of the canvas, not the frame.

Comment: Why do you need the keys in order to use the scrollbar? It's only a bug in returning the keys. Internally, the scrollbar is fine.

Comment: I tried to use it like in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40299215/add-the-attribute-in-existing-elements-in-tkinter/40299883#40299883 but it doesn't work on Mac.

Comment: The scrollbar isn't even visible directly, I can only see a white rectangle where the scrollbar should be. I also can't scroll.

Comment: That has nothing to do with the fact that `sb.keys()` returns a list of empty strings. The problems are completely unrelated.

Comment: i just tried to explain how i found the bug. you asked for the reason why i need a list of keys, but that also has nothing to do with the fact. i guess i didn't ask how to fix my actual problem in the question. should i ask a new question about the problem i want to fix? that's what i would do now

Comment: I would suggest you to use `tkinter.scrolledtext` (it is called `ScrolledText` in Python 2.7) widget to achieve what you want to do. It works perfectly fine on my computer.